# Best way to get properties from a struct and use as labels?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, label

Developing an app for iOS, I have created a struct and have also created an array that is filled with objects of the struct. There are two properties of the struct `flavors` and `descrip`. I want to take each `flavor` property from each item in the array and use it to fill a table view cell's label. There are six items in the array so I want six labels so that it corresponds. So label one should be chocolate chip, label 2 honey, label 3 sugar, and so on. All suggestions and tips are highly appreciated.

```
Import UIKit

class FlavorController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var flavorTable: UITableView!

struct cookieInfo {
    var flavor: String
    var descrip: String

}

var cookies = [cookieInfo(flavor: "Chocolate Chip", descrip: "Filled with gooey, milk chocholate! A classic!"), cookieInfo(flavor: "Honey", descrip: "Baked and drizzled with 100% pure honey, a must-have for sweet lovers!"), cookieInfo(flavor: "Sugar", descrip: "Simplicity meets savory, a sugar cookie topped with sweet icing!"), cookieInfo(flavor: "Peanut Butter", descrip: "A cookie infused with creamy peanut butter, the perfect cookie treat!"), cookieInfo(flavor: "Snickerdoodle", descrip: "Sugar cookie coated in cinnamon & sugar, baked to perfection!"),cookieInfo(flavor: "Shortbread", descrip: "An underrated yet flavorful cookie just like your grandma used to make!")]



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return cookies.count

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FlavorCellTableViewCell

    //this is where I want to the text of each flavorLabel to be the flavor property of the struct
    cell.flavorLabel.text = ??

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Note that it is Swift convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter. Btw Info is redundant I would name it plain `Cookie` and change `descrip` property name to `info` or `detail`.

Comment: Btw don't forget to set the view controller as the tableview delegate and dataSource in viewDidLoad or in your IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple array access followed by simply field access.

```
let cookie = cookies[indexPath.row]
let flavor = cookie.flavor
cell.flavorLabel.text = flavor
```

Or, more simply:

```
cell.flavorLabel.text = cookies[indexPath.row].flavor
```